# how to remove specific html tags with one line using javascript regex code

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to keep only all these tags `<strong></strong> , <em></em>, <p></p> , <strike></strike>` etc right now i am using JavaScript regex like this.

```
var s = "<div><p>p tag</p> <strike>Strike</strike> <strong>strong</strong> in <u>underline</u> <em>italic</em> <span>this is span tag</span> <img src=''><br> final words</div>";
console.log(s.replace(/\<(?!strong|br|em|p|u|strike).*?\>/g, ""));
```

It is working 50% fine because it is not removing my defined html tags, but problem is it is removing all end tags here is how i am getting the output

**Output :**

```
<p>p tag <strike>Strike <strong>strong in <u>underline <em>italic this is span tag <br> final words
```

but i need the output something like this

**Required Output:**

```
<p>p tag</p> <strike>Strike</strike> <strong>strong</strong> in <u>underline</u> <em>italic</em> this is span tag <br> final words
```

Is there any javascript expert there who could help me with this i really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Don't use regex to match or parse HTML tags, it's kind of overcomplicating things .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match closing tags with an optional `/` right after the `<` and use positive lookahead for a word character (to ensure `/` doesn't get matched):

```js
var s = "<div><p>p tag</p> <strike>Strike</strike> <strong>strong</strong> in <u>underline</u> <em>italic</em> <span>this is span tag</span> <img src=''><br> final words</div>";
console.log(s.replace(/<\/?(?=\w)(?!strong|br|em|p|u|strike).*?>/g, ""));
//                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

But regular expressions *generally* shouldn't be used in an attempt to parse anything but the most trivial HTML